# CreateWindow is not working

Tags: c++, visual-c++, hwnd, qdialog, createwindow

My project is a console application that returns a DLL. I also use it in another project.

This project is using `WFS` methods. In one of those methods, I need to pass `HWND` as a parameter. The reason is that whenever a method wants to send a message (event in my case), it will use this `HWND`.

First I tried this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WFS_EXECUTE_EVENT: 
    case WFS_SERVICE_EVENT: 
    case WFS_USER_EVENT: 
    case WFS_SYSTEM_EVENT:
        return S_OK;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam );
}


HWND create(HWND parent) 
{
    HINSTANCE inst =  GetModuleHandle (0);
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;

    wincl.hInstance = inst;
    wincl.lpszClassName = TEXT("ConsoleClass");
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;    

    HWND mainWindow = CreateWindow( 
        TEXT("DM_Class_Name"),       
        TEXT("DM_Title"),            
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 
        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
        CW_USEDEFAULT,      
        CW_USEDEFAULT,       
        CW_USEDEFAULT,     
        (HWND) NULL,         
        (HMENU) NULL,       
        inst,                
        (LPVOID) NULL);      

    ShowWindow(mainWindow,1);

    return mainWindow;

}
```

It's not working for some reason. The windows is not showing and HWND is always `NULL`.

Why isn't it working?

After a few hours of searching, I tried `QDialog`:

```
QDialog dialog;
dialog.setObjectName("Device_Manager_Dialog");
dialog.setWindowTitle("Device Manager");
dialog.setFixedWidth(10);
dialog.setFixedHeight(10);
dialog.show();
dialog.setVisible(false);
QWidget * widget = dialog.window();
HWND windows_handle = widget->effectiveWinId();
```

It's working in this way. I created a window and HWND and in the class I need to use this `HWND`.

I call the following line to get it:

```
windows_handle = FindWindow(0, TEXT("Device Manager"));
```

If I want to use `qdialog`, how can I assign `WndProc` to `qdialog` or `widget` so I can get messages that the `WFS` method will send?

Comment: Have you actually registered a window class called `DM_Class_Name`? You have a half filled-out `WNDCLASSEX` structure with a different class name, and no call that I can see to `RegisterClassEx().`

Comment: class name is ok, I should change it here, Anyway i used RegisterClassEx, Still same prob, Any other suggestion ?!

Comment: PS: I used it before and also after the createwindow() still no result.

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem:

The class name must be the same when i want to create window as well.

```
WNDCLASS Wclass;

...

Wclass.lpszClassName = TEXT("Device_Manager_Class_Name");

...

HWND gHwnd = NULL;

gHwnd = CreateWindow(TEXT("Device_Manager_Class_Name")

...
```

Special thanks to Jonathan Potter who guided me to it.